# list of coordinates with unknown projection

Tags: coordinate-system

I've a list of coordinates which were recorded in a last years aerial survey. Besides this I've the flightlog. The list of coordinates was created "manually" by writing down the position into a spreadsheet.

The projection of the flightlog data is: WGS84, EPSG4326

This files works fine and the locations seem to be correct.

Now I'd like to create a point-shapefile from my excel-spreadsheet. The problem right now, is that I don't have any information of the used projection. When I try to use EPSG4326 I get a gap (see screenshot).

[image]

The coordinates are as follows:

S074233 E0341051

S074109 E0340115

S073729 E0340115

S071631 E0342037

S071628 E0342837

S071409 E0343446

S071525 E0343546

I'm a bit perplex. Maybe important to know that they maybe used Skydemon or Garmin as GPS recorder. The area of interest is in Tanzania. I've access to ArcGIS and QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

These coordinates are just WGS84 degrees, but written as degree-minutes-seconds without any delimiter.

With an excel sheet, it should be easy to separate them and put them into a decimal degrees format, with a trailing minus for the southern hemisphere.

As an example, `S074233 E0341051` should be converted to

```
 - (´07`+`42`/60+`33`/3600) = -7.70916667
    `034`+`10`/60+`51`/3600 = 34.18083333
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried it but failed, maybe I miss something. Could you give an example for the first pair of coordinates? How it should look like...

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I've tried this and the point appears closer to my flightlog/track but is still ~1,8km off the line. I can image that there is some uncertainty when they recorded the points with the handheld GPS because the plane is moving, but is such an enormous inaccuracy possible?

Comment: one question about that, are the points in good relation to each other, (i.e. they make a good line) but all uniformly off?  It could be a different geographic coordinate system (don't know what it would be though) if that's the case.

Comment: I forgot to put brackets around my first formula. Can you try again? I doubt that GPS track something else than WGS84, not sure about the flight log.